# Android rendering fails

Tags: android, class, rendering

I recently installed Android studio on Ubuntu. I always get a rendering problem as saying there some classes are missing. I googled the problem but I didn't found an answer for the problem.

[image]

Comment: In design mode, Change the API version to lower value

Comment: already tried.. not going to solve it..